# "Antiforcing" - Is there a method to 'remove' sets from a model of ZF?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing

Forcing is a method of "adding sets" to a model $M$ of ZF by making a new set $M^{(\mathbb{P})}$ consisting of every set of $M$, but you have the option to add certain sets out of $M^{(\mathbb{P})}$ as to guarantee you get a new model of ZF.

Intuitively, if you force with a bunch of functions from $\omega^M$ to $\omega_1^M$, then in the new model, what was once $\omega_1^M$ is now a countable ordinal. This is choosing to keep as many sets in $M^{(\mathcal{P})}$ which are "evidence that $|\omega_1^M|=\aleph_0$" as possible. (OVERSIMPLIFICATION)

---

The reason this is effective for CH is because it makes $\omega_1^M$ *look smaller* by adding enough such functions to the universe. The idea is that you add things which are "evidence of your axiom being true" and discard nearly everything else.

The question is this: could you also **remove** things which are "evidence of your axiom being false?"

Let's say there is this magical method of doing this called ***antiforcing.*** It would have some interesting applications:

1. Perhaps, starting in a model of the axiom of determinacy, one could antiforce with winning strategies to make a model of ZF in which the axiom of determinacy fails.
2. Starting in a model of the existence of a certain large cardinal, say, a measurable cardinal, it may be possible to antiforce with $\kappa$-complete nonprinciple ultrafilters, leaving $\kappa$ a non-measurable cardinal, but intuitively not "collapsing" anything; that is, the cardinals around it are undisturbed.
3. Most importantly (and the real reason I was thinking of this), starting with a model of $V\neq K$ for some core model $K$, and a large cardinal $\kappa$ with $|(\kappa^+)^K|\neq\kappa^+$, one could antiforce with many surjections from $\kappa$ to $(\kappa^+)^K$, making a model of $K$ in which $(\kappa^+)^K=\kappa^+$.

You may be wondering why the last one is important; well, it's a way to "antiforce the sharp away" for a given core model. This could perhaps mean that, starting with the existence of a large cardinal $\kappa$ with cardinal property $P$, if this method of "antiforcing" preserves $P$, then the existence of a cardinal with $P$ doesn't imply the sharp exists; meaning that $K$ is an inner model for $P$.

---

**Here's the question: Has this been thought of before (I assume it has)? What would be some good ways to go about doing it? (Of course, using an inner model would work, but I want a method more similar to 'undoing' forcing rather than just removing all non-constructable sets).**

Comment: I may misunderstand, but "removing" sets was initially considered as easier, leading to proofs of the consistency of AC or CH (assuming that of ZF), much before Cohen introduced forcing to prove consistency of their negation.

Comment: You should probably read about set-theoretic geology and its inner model-theoretic version.

Comment: I understand what inner model theory is; I meant a sort of different method which is standardized (there are only a couple known inner models, meanwhile there are many known forcing universes). Specifically, I would like to know if there is a method of making inner-model-like things similar to "undoing" forcing.

Comment: @YCor this is true; but not all sets can be removed (in particular none of the constructible sets can be removed). Also, as far as I know, removing sets but preserving others is a bit more difficult, which is what "antiforcing" would be used for. Of course, not being able to remove constructible sets isn't a problem because any inner model contains all of the constructible sets anyways.

Comment: @KeithMillar Assuming we're talking about inner models with the same ordinals, shouldn't it be the case that it's possible to remove some set $A$ while preserving some set $B$ if and only if $A \notin L(B)$?

Comment: Keith, I didn't just say inner model theory, but rather inner model-theoretic geology. In any case, one of the key motivators of inner model theory is very close to what you are after. The evolution of covering lemmas illustrates this dramatically.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I see. Thank you! This is a quite interesting subject. I believe you are right that this is exactly what I am after.

Comment: Can you do me a small favor, and *stop* giving weird names to everything? Especially if you ask "Hey, did someone think about this concept yet".

Comment: @AsafKaragila I suppose so, if it would make it easier to read. It just helps me to think of it like it already exists so I can surmise some properties it would have if it were to exist. I see your point though.

Comment: Your question is too vague to say much more than what Andrés already did by way of an answer. Concerning your item 3, though, which large cardinals $\kappa$ do you have in mind? $|(\kappa^{+})^K| = \kappa$ is plain false if $\kappa$ is weakly compact (or e.g. carries a precipitous ideal).

Comment: Oh, that's correct. I should have said "in which $|(\kappa^+)^K|\neq\kappa^+$."

Comment: ?? $|(\kappa^+)^K| \not= \kappa^+$ is equivalent with $|(\kappa^+)^K|=\kappa$.

Comment: I see what you meant. I think that this would show that a specific large cardinals with NO known inner models, one could "antiforce" into a model in which $|(\kappa^+)^M|=\kappa^+$ for a given inner model $M$.